# Перенаправляет на пустую страницу если в форме найдены ошибки

Tags: php, форма

Есть форма:

```
action="тут обработчик" method="post"
```

и есть вот такой обработчик:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["send1"]))  {
$to = '...@bk.ru';
$from = htmlspecialchars($_POST["emailtext"]);
$subject = "какой-то текст";
$msg_box = "";

$avtonumber1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["breloksnomerom1"]);
$avtonumber2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST["breloksnomerom2"]);
if ($_REQUEST[$_brelokstextom]=='on') {
    $breloktext = htmlspecialchars($_POST["breloktext"]);
} else $breloktext = "без текста";


if ($_POST['packaging'] == '0') {
    $packaging = "ппп";
};
if ($_POST['packaging'] == '20') {
    $packaging = "пкуп";
};


if ($_POST['delivery'] == 'free') {
    $delivery = "кпкуп";
};
if ($_POST['delivery'] == 'spb') {
    $delivery = "пкуп";
};
if ($_POST['delivery'] == 'russia') {
    $delivery = "пкп";
};



$added_text = htmlspecialchars($_POST["added_text"]);
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
$tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tel"]);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["emailtext"]);

$message = " Номер автомобиля: $avtonumber1 $avtonumber2 \r\n Или текст: $breloktext \r\n Упаковка: $packaging \r\n Способ доставки: $delivery \r\n Пожелания к заказу: $added_text \r\n Имя: $name \r\n Телефон: $tel \r\n Хочу получить подтверждение заказа на почту: $email";

$_SESSION["breloksnomerom1"] = $avtonumber1;
$_SESSION["breloksnomerom2"] = $avtonumber2;
$_SESSION["added_text"] = $added_text;
$_SESSION["name"] = $name;
$_SESSION["tel"] = $tel;
$_SESSION["emailtext"] = $email;


$error_name = "";
$error_tel = "";
$error = false;
if($name == "") {
    $error_name = "Введите ваше имя";
    $error = true;
};
if($tel == "") {
    $error_tel = "Введите телефон для связи";
    $error = true;
};

if(!$error) {
    $subject = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=";
    $headers = "From: $from\r\nReply-to: $from\r\nContent-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    header("Location: success.php?send=1");
    exit; 
} 
}
```

Если поля `name` и `tel` заполнены - всё отлично работает, форма отправляется и пользователь переходит на `success.php?send=1`?. Но если эти поля не заполнены, то его перекидывает на пустую страницу. Как так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На страничку "success.php?send=1" скрипт редиректит если вызывается строка

```
header("Location: success.php?send=1");
```

а она будет вызвана, если

```
if(!$error) {
```

но в скрипте мы устанавливаем значение:

```
$error = true;
```

если

```
if($name == "") {
```

или

```
if($tel == "") {
```

Чтобы была не пустая страничка, надо отобразить страничку на который была форма и дополнительно оповести об ошибках, это просто недописано в скрипте, случай с ошибкой ввода не обрабатывается

Comment: Ёмаё, ошибка то простая была =) всё решила, спасибо большое